# Why is flume not writing data to S3 in Mumbai region?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, flume, flume-ng

I am using flume 1.5.0 version to migrate SQL server data to Amazon S3.
I am migrating only incremental data to s3. So its something like whenever a new record gets inserted into my sql server then it should be replicate on S3.

**I can write sql server data to s3 in north virginia region**, but when I create a bucket in mumbai region and write data in mumbai region then its throwing below error-

```
19/09/07 13:01:08 WARN hdfs.HDFSEventSink: HDFS IO error
java.io.IOException: s3n://BUCKET-NAME : 400 : Bad Request
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:411)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:181)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy8.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.create(NativeS3FileSystem.java:403)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:776)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.doOpen(HDFSDataStream.java:86)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSDataStream.open(HDFSDataStream.java:113)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:273)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$1.call(BucketWriter.java:262)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9$1.run(BucketWriter.java:718)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.runPrivileged(BucketWriter.java:183)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter.access$1700(BucketWriter.java:59)
at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.BucketWriter$9.call(BucketWriter.java:715)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException: 400 Bad Request
```

My flume conf sink properties are as below-

```
# SINK
agent.sinks = s3hdfs
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.path =  s3n://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@BUCKET-NAME/test
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.filePrefix = test
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.rollSize = 67108864  #64Mb filesize
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.batchSize = 100
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.hdfs.rollInterval = 1
agent.sinks.s3hdfs.channel = ch1
```

I tried S3a instead of S3n but it also did not work.

So please suggest me what changes I need to make so it can write to S3 bucket in mumbai region. If I need to mention region name in flume conf file, then how would I mention that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

S3n is obsolete. S3A will work with it -look at the hadoop docs on fs.s3a.endpoint and signing algorithm. These are supported in Hadoop 2.8+

Comment: I tried with hadoop 2.8 version but still I am not able to write into S3 in Mumbai region

Comment: Can you please suggest me how to add aws signatureV4 in flume conf?

Comment: https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3-per-bucket-region-configs.html

Comment: Thanks ..I'll try this and will let u know